# How can I use flex to make iframe stretch to full screen?

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox

I can only get my entire iframe height to display if I hard code the height to 1000px, but setting height to 100% doesn't work. For whatever reason the width stretches all the way using 100%, just not height. If I try to assign 100% to the .full-width class, the iframe just doesn't display at all. I am looking for the iframe to stretch to the full size of the window for different screen sizes as well.

```
<div class="fullheight-container">
  <div class="flex flex-auto flex-v-arrange">
    <div class="flex flex-auto">
      <iframe #window1 class="full-width" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0"
        src="/source/iframe"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.fullheight-container {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-auto {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flex-v-arrange {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `width: 100vw; height: 100vh`?

Answer (score 3):

iframes do not allow an automatic height. The height needs to be a fixed value. As mentioned you can use 100vh as height.
Alternativly, you can have the needed height of the iframe calculated. For that you need to use JS. use this for the iframes content:

```html
<body onLoad="resizeParent();">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeParent() {
      var height = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollHeight;
      window.parent.postMessage(["setIframeHeight", height], "*");
    }
  </script>
  
  <!-- Content here -->
</body>
```

Then you need to add a corresponding code line with JS into the page that contains the iframe itself:

```html
<iframe id="superFrame" src="" style="width: 100%; border: none;" onload="resizeIframe(this)" scrolling="no">Alternative</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('superFrame');
    var eventName = e.data[0];
    var height = e.data[1];
    switch(eventName) {
      case 'setIframeHeight':
        iframe.height = height;
        break;
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set: `width: 100vw;` or `height: 100vh;` for the height.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

I set the below on your parent container:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

and set `height/width: 100%;` on full-width class.

Additionally added `display: flex` to your parent container as well.

```css
.fullheight-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-width {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullheight-container">
  <iframe #window1 class="full-width" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" src="/source/iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working. However, I am still seeing a scroll bar on the right, where I would like that to not be there. Is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: See my updated snippet. I removed some of your code since we are mostly working with the parent div and iframe.